# how to delete all characters in file with combination of cat and tr cmd linux?

Tags: cat, tr

I need to delete entire file content, I tried this:

```
cat file | tr -d "*" 
cat file | tr -d ""
```

> The Tea Research Institute (TRI) was established in Sept ember 1958,
> affiliated with the Chinese Academy of Agric ulture Sciences (CAAS).
> It is located in Hangzhou, Zheji ang Province. As the only
> comprehensive national researc h institution of public service
> specializing in Chinese  tea industry, and also one of the worldwide
> known instit utions focusing on tea plant (Camellia sinensis) researc
> h including tea germplasm, tea breeding, tea cultivation , tea
> processing and manufactory

how to delete using cat and tr?

Comment: `> file` should be enough. Or `cat /dev/null > file`

Comment: @MarkSetchell, no, it s asking to do it using combination of tr and cat

Comment: Ok `cat /dev/null | tr a b > file`

Comment: Maybe your project was hoping you'd find out about char classes, `echo "The Tea Research Institute (TRI) was " | tr -d '[[:punct:][:alpha:]]'` will get yoiu started. `man tr` will show you the others. Good luck.